# KVO on NSMutableString not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

I'm trying to observe changes to an NSMutableString `isDetailView`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isDetailView" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [isDetailView setString:@"YES"];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"obersedValueFOrKeyPath:%@", keyPath);
}
```

But the observeValueForKeyPath method never gets called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not changing the property, only the content of the object it points to.  If you make `isDetailView` a normal string and do

```
[self setIsDetailView: @"YES"]
```

it will work.

By the way, properties that start "is" are conventionally supposed to be boolean and that looks like a more appropriate type in this case too.

Comment: Oh I see, this did it. Well, initially isDetailView was a BOOL, but I don't think that works with KVO. Or does it? What about NSNumber?

Comment: And KVO works fine for booleans, even though it's a basic type.